# React & Javascript: Issues Removing Duplicate Values from Array

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, arrays

I am working in react and Javascript and have an array object that is like so:

```
const Regions = [
  { REGION_CODE: 'ABC', REGION_NAME: 'SOMEREGION1', OFFICES: [
    {OFFICE_CODE: 'ABD', OFFICE_NAME: 'SOMEOFFICE'},
     ... // Dozens of unique entries for this region
  ]},
  { REGION_CODE: 'ABD', REGION_NAME: 'SOMEREGION2', OFFICES: [
    {OFFICE_CODE: 'CDF', OFFICE_NAME: 'SOMEOFFICE2'}
     ... // Dozens of unique entries for this region
  ]},
  ... // several similar entries
]
```

The issue I have with the array is that several of the Regions entries have offices that share an office code with other Regions. The end goal is that I have a search filter that lists all unique office codes when "All Regions" is selected. However, despite other Q&A I have searched through, I am failing to get the duplicates to be removed.

I have tried the following:

```
//Variant 1
const Offices = []
Regions.forEach(region => {
  region.OFFICES.forEach(office => {
    if(!Offices.includes(office)) {
      Offices.push(office)
    }
  }
});

//Variant 2
const Offices = []
Regions.forEach(region => {
  region.OFFICES.forEach(office => {
    if(Offices.indexOf(office) === -1) {
      Offices.push(office)
    }
  }
});

//Variant 3
const Offices = []
Regions.forEach(region => {
  region.OFFICES.forEach(office => {
    Offices.push(office)
  }
});
const UniqueOffices = Array.from(new Set(Offices));
```

To my understanding, all of the above "should" work, but the results I get are always the same with it just giving me back all entries instead of just the unique ones. I have even tried using the map version instead, but that I am almost certain I am misunderstanding something. When I simplify the array to something like

```
const item = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'a']
```

Or

```
const item = [ 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4 ]
```

The above seems to work without any issues...

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Any suggestions on how to fix this issue? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Adding this here until the edit limit time period is expired: I want to make it clear that the shared office codes also share the same office name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.includes` (and `Array.indexOf`) only check reference equality for objects. It means that the following expression will always be false:

```js
{} == {}
```

Because `{}` makes a new object with a different reference each time.

To make your code work, you need to compare each office `OFFICE_CODE` and you can do it by using `Array.some` or `Array.find` like this:

```js
const Regions = [{
    REGION_CODE: 'ABC',
    REGION_NAME: 'SOMEREGION1',
    OFFICES: [{
        OFFICE_CODE: 'ABD',
        OFFICE_NAME: 'SOMEOFFICE'
      },
      // Dozens of unique entries for this region
    ]
  },
  {
    REGION_CODE: 'ABD',
    REGION_NAME: 'SOMEREGION2',
    OFFICES: [{
        OFFICE_CODE: 'CDF',
        OFFICE_NAME: 'SOMEOFFICE2'
      }, {
        OFFICE_CODE: 'ABD',
        OFFICE_NAME: 'SOMEOFFICE'
      }
      // Dozens of unique entries for this region
    ]
  },
  // several similar entries
];

const Offices = [];
Regions.forEach(region => {
  region.OFFICES.forEach(newOffice => {
    if (!Offices.some(office => office.OFFICE_CODE === newOffice.OFFICE_CODE)) {
      Offices.push(newOffice)
    }
  });
});

console.log(Offices);

const Offices2 = [];
Regions.forEach(region => {
  region.OFFICES.forEach(newOffice => {
    if (!Offices2.find(office => office.OFFICE_CODE === newOffice.OFFICE_CODE)) {
      Offices2.push(newOffice)
    }
  });
});

console.log(Offices2);
```

Comment: You rock! Thanks,  that got me what I wanted. Much appreciated